# Conditional inclusion of paragraph (org-export)

Tags: org-mode, org-export

It seems the `@@latex: @@` and `@@odt: @@` does not work for lists or paragraphs with blank lines.
For instance

```
@@odt:
  - Xyzzy!

  - Nothing happens
@@
```

is exported to latex.

How can I have some paragraphs exported only by one backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @@backend: @@ construct doesn't work with newlines. I think you can do something like this to get a selective export only for a particular backend, in this case html. I am not sure if you can also get other non-html formatting in this.

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
conditional

multi

line

paragraph
#+END_EXPORT
```

Comment: Interesting but the text is formatted as a code block

Comment: good point. I have edited the answer with an export block instead.

Comment: Is it possible to have a #+INCLUDE: "./xxx.org" in the export block? My attempt do not result as expected (#+BEGIN_EXPORT  is typesetted and the include not taken into account, whatever the export mode).

Comment: This includes the content in the block when exported to HTML, but the content is interpreted as html code. Is it possible for the content to be in org-mode syntax and exported as usual to html code? There is some content I want to export to html, but not to latex.